# R: Corrplot() heatmap manipulation?

Tags: r, heatmap, correlation, r-corrplot

I have 2 data sets, [one](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X6kEWONEzN3_k6ZwNsBd39nPz6ZqaFIDLpvOf6XQce8/edit?usp=sharing) being 264 columns and the [other](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wWey1S7owfNXRLg4p23ynmSmvFauF_YIg6WZNxBzYP8/edit?usp=sharing) being 19 columns.

After running a Pearson's correlation using `cor()` I try plotting the output in a heatmap using `corrplot()`, but it's unreadable.

How can I edit my code to fix [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfSMn.jpg)?

My code is below:

```
    library("corrplot")
    D1=VGT5
    D2=BFT5
    CorTest=cor(D1, y=D2, use = "everything", method = "pearson")
    CorGraph=corrplot(CorTest, method = "circle", col = colorRampPalette(c("blue","white","red"))(200), title = "Pearson's Correlation of High-Fat Sugar at 12 weeks", tl.cex = .75, tl.col = "Black",diag = TRUE, cl.ratio = 2.25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your correlation matrix has 19 rows and 264 columns. The graphical representation of this matrix is rather problematic. Here are two possibile solutions.
(1) Plot the whole matrix

```
library(ggcorrplot)
png(file="CorrPlot1.png", height=10000, width=3000, res=600)
ggcorrplot(CorTest, lab_size=.1)+
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=6),
      axis.text.x = element_text(size=6, angle=90))
dev.off()
```

(2) Cut the matrix in two pieces

```
library(gridExtra)
nc <- ncol(CorTest)
png(file="CorrPlot2.png", height=7000, width=7000, res=600)
p1 <- ggcorrplot(CorTest[,1:(nc/2)], lab_size=.1)+
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=6),
      axis.text.x = element_text(size=6, angle=90))
p2 <- ggcorrplot(CorTest[,(nc/2+1):nc], lab_size=.1)+
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=6),
      axis.text.x = element_text(size=6, angle=90))
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! What package is ggcorrplot a part of?

Comment: Could you link the download for the package? I can't find it. I have found ggcorplot() in the Deducer package but can't locate that one.

Comment: the code works fine, but I cannot get the actual image to populate. Is that where the .png comes in? I cannot find that saved anywhere on my computer.

Comment: Try with `getwd()`. You will get the path of your working directory

Comment: It says that the Corrplot.png does not exist when I getwd()

Comment: Error in getwd(CorrPlot1.png) : unused argument (CorrPlot1.png)

Comment: @Haley I asked you to try `getwd()` not  `getwd(CorrPlot1.png)` !